# AngularJs - ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following two input fields. The only difference is `ng-disabled` directive.

So, there is repetition of code.I am looking forward to use only one `input` tag for by fulfilling both purposes.

How i can combine these two inputs with showing/hiding `ng-disabled` directive based on condition?

```
<input type="radio" name="student_role" ng-model="student.RoleId" />

<input type="radio" name="role" ng-disabled="loggedStudent == student.Student.Email" ng-model="student.RoleId"  />
```

Comment: ng-show with the reversed conditions? Or am I understanding the question wrong?

Comment: what are your purposes you mentioned in the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try

```
<input type="radio" name="role" ng-disabled="(loggedStudent == student.Student.Email) ? true : false" ng-model="student.RoleId"  />
```

Comment: i think it works. lemme give another try before marking it Answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
    <input type="radio" name="role" ng-if="loggedStudent == student.Student.Email" ng-model="student.RoleId"  />
```